# I get SQL error converting data type varchar to date

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I get

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure DetayliArama, Line 0 Error
>   converting data type varchar to date.

error. Any ideas?

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[DetayliArama]
(
@ilktarih date = null,
@sontarih date = null,
@islem nvarchar(10) = null,
@birim int = null
)
as
declare @sorgu nvarchar (max)
set @sorgu = 'select KasaID,Aciklama,Tutar,Tarih,Islem,IsDeleted,KasalarID 
from KasaTable where IsDeleted=0 and KasalarID='+CONVERT(varchar(10),@birim)+' AND ' 
if (@islem is not null) 
    set @sorgu += 'Islem like ''%'+@islem+'%'' and '
if (@ilktarih is not null) 
    set @sorgu+='Tarih between '+convert(datetime,@ilktarih,120)+' 
        and '+convert(datetime,@sontarih ,120)+' and '                      
set @sorgu+='1=1 order by Tarih DESC'
exec (@sorgu)
```

Comment: I usually debug this sort of thing by running logic as standalone sql and inspect the variables you're trying to convert. If you do this, what is the varchar value that you're trying to convert to a date?

Comment: Also you should use `exec sp_executesql`, not `exec()`. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) you need to surround your date/datetime variables with single quotes. Otherwise the query ends up like:

```
WHERE Tarih BETWEEN 2012-03-14 ...
```

Which gets evaluated as a numeric expression, so ends up being:

```
WHERE Tarih BETWEEN 1995 ... -- and no that's not the year
```

(b) you shouldn't be converting to DATETIME. Try:

```
set @sorgu+='Tarih between '''+convert(CHAR(8),@ilktarih,112)+'''
  and '''+convert(CHAR(8),@sontarih ,112)+''' and '
```

However I fail to see why you're using dynamic SQL at all. Why not:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DetayliArama]
  @ilktarih DATE         = NULL,
  @sontarih DATE         = NULL,
  @islem    NVARCHAR(10) = NULL,
  @birim    INT          = NULL
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT KasaID, Aciklama, Tutar, Tarih, Islem, IsDeleted, KasalarID 
    FROM dbo.KasaTable 
    WHERE IsDeleted = 0 
    AND KasalarID = @birim
    AND Islem LIKE COALESCE('%'+@islem+'%', Islem)
    AND Tarih BETWEEN COALESCE(@ilktarih, '19000101') 
        AND COALESCE(@sontarih, '20301231');
END
GO
```

In some cases it can be more efficient to use dynamic SQL to avoid bad plans due to different parameters. But I think you should deal with that when you come across it.

Comment: so I new to sql thk u to solve my prblem and show me another way